# webMethods: Show/hide caf_h:panelBlock based on property value of backing bean

Tags: webmethods, webmethods-caf

We have got two caf_h:panelBlock elements (`id="panel1"` and `id="panel2"`) in a CAF portlet which are supposed to be rendered based on a property of the backing bean (`rendered="#{ViewBean.property}"` and `rendered="#{not ViewBean.property}"`).

So the XHTML of such a panel locks as follows:

```
<caf_h:panelBlock id="panel1" rendered="#{ViewBean.property}">
    content
</caf_h:panelBlock>
```

The property of the backing bean is declared as follows:

```
private java.lang.Boolean property;
```

And initialized in the bean's Initialize() method:

```
public String initialize() {
    this.property = true;
}
```

The tricky part comes now: We want to show/hide these panels by clicking on a command link:

```
<caf_h:commandLink action="#{ViewBean.click}" id="commandLink"></caf_h:commandLink>
```

The bean method called by this command link, in turn, changes the property's value:

```
public String click() {
    this.property = false;
}
```

However, the visibility/rendering of the block panels is not affected at all. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the above mentioned way works fine if the `ViewBean.property` is not changed again later during the portlet life cycle - as we accidentally did in our case in the `beforeRenderResponse()` method.